# Aggregation on aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb4.0

We have a collection as follows - Batches`(0,1,2 etc)` running jobs in chunks.
Each batch would have multiple chunks/documents having jobs.

We need to aggregate jobs for each batch.
Thereafter,job count of each batch needs to be subtracted from that of batch `'0'`.

The result would be an array/collection of the difference of job counts of each batch with batch 0 respectively.
If there are 'x' batches,the size of the array would be x-1 obviously.

Can this be done in a single aggregation operation?

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("xxxxxx"),
    "batch": ["0"],
    "jobs":2500
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("xxxxxx"),
    "batch": ["1"],
    "jobs":1500
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("xxxxxx"),
    "batch": ["0"],
    "jobs":1500
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("xxxxxx"),
    "batch": ["2"],
    "jobs":3500
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("xxxxxx"),
    "batch": ["1"],
    "jobs":500
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("xxxxxx"),
    "batch": ["0"],
    "jobs":1500
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("xxxxxx"),
    "batch": ["3"],
    "jobs":2500
},
```

Expected output:

```
[ 3500,2000,3000]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$batch' },
    { $group: { _id: '$batch', count: { $sum: '$jobs' } } },
    { $group: { _id: '', data: { $push: '$$ROOT' } } },
    {
        $addFields: {
            value: { $filter: { input: '$data', as: 'e', cond: { $eq: ['$$e._id', '0'] } } }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            data: { $filter: { input: { $map: { input: '$data', as: 'e', in: { $subtract: [{ $arrayElemAt: ['$value.count', 0] }, '$$e.count'] } } }, as: 'e', cond: { $ne: ['$$e', 0] } } }
        }
    }])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4IIi57m1Yip)